# How to name anonymous type with string?

Tags: javascript, razor, reflection

So, I have some JavaScript:

```
var myThing = { userId: dataItem.UserID, permissionID: dataItem.PermissionID };
```

What I'd like, however, is to have this in C#:

```
var userIdHtmlId = '@nameof(MyDto.UserID)';
var permissionIdHtmlId = '@nameof(MyDto.PermissionID)';
```

and then in JavaScript, somehow do something like this:

```
var userId = dataItem.GetValueByReflectionOrSomething(userIdHtmlId);
var permissionID = dataItem.GetValueByReflectionOrSomething(permissionIdHtmlId);
var myThing = { userId: userIdHtmlId, permissionID: permissionID };
```

...but have no idea how.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Are you looking for `dataItem[userIdHtmlId]`?

Comment: @georg That is exactly what I needed, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just for ease of reading, I'm putting georg's comment as an Answer.)

`dataItem[userIdHtmlId]`